# Recycler viewer linear layout manager with Null Pointer Exception

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Though this question has been asked several times here on this forum. I had read them but none of them worked for me at least. I am tying this for almost 2 days but couldn't figure it out how to initialize the linear layout and escaping the NPE. I am not using any fragments and wants to initialize the layout manager in activity.

Below is important part of my code, rest of the code is same about adapter and xml so not writing down here.... but in case it is needed, i ll provide that as well.

```
public class MainNews extends AppCompatActivity {

    public RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    private String[] inputStream;
    public RecyclerView recyclerView;
    //ArrayList<Data> dataList;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_news);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        String newsMain = "http://microblogging.wingnity.com/JSONParsingTutorial/jsonActors";
        new JSONAsync(getApplicationContext()).execute(newsMain);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this, JSONAsync.dataArray);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    public static class JSONAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, Boolean> {

        Context context;
        public static List<Data> dataArray;

        public JSONAsync(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                return downloadUrl(params[0]);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return false;
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

       public boolean downloadUrl(String myurl) throws IOException,JSONException {
            InputStream is = null;
            int response;

            try {
                URL url = new URL(myurl);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                // Starts the query
                conn.connect();
                response = conn.getResponseCode();
                is = conn.getInputStream();
                if (response == 200) {
                    String responseBody = convertStreamToString(conn.getInputStream());
                    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(responseBody);
                    //  JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(is);
                    for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jobj = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        Data data = new Data();
                        data.setId(jobj.getInt("id"));
                        data.setHeading(jobj.getString("heading"));
                        data.setBrief(jobj.getString("brief"));
                        data.setDate(jobj.getString("date"));
                        dataArray.add(data);
                    }
                    return true;
                } else return false;

            } finally {
                if (is != null) {
                    is.close();
                }
            }

        }

        public String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            try {
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line).append("\n");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
            } finally {
                try {
                    is.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }

            return sb.toString();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

            if (result == true) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Data Fetched, now do some work with it AH", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else
                Toast.makeText(context, "Unable to fetch data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
       }
       }
```

Here is logcat.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: admin.myproject, PID: 11032
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean java.util.List.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
    at admin.myproject.MainNews$JSONAsync.downloadUrl(MainNews.java:128)
    at admin.myproject.MainNews$JSONAsync.doInBackground(MainNews.java:90)
    at admin.myproject.MainNews$JSONAsync.doInBackground(MainNews.java:78)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) enter code here
```

P.S: I have made JSONAsync class static/non static and other things were changed but nothings worked.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: can you post your log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dataArray is not initialized. change it to

```
public static List<Data> dataArray = new Arraylist();
```

Comment: well, u r genius :D ... and I dont knw which words should I use for me ! Since XML is not inflating out completely as i wanted but still your solution removes the barrier . Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your array list which you are trying to add in which is never initialized . you have to initialized it first before adding any value.

Try this

```
public static List<Data> dataArray = new Arraylist();
```

or you can do it as following also

```
List<Data> dataArray;

public boolean downloadUrl(String myurl) throws IOException,JSONException {
    InputStream is = null;
    int response;
    dataArray = new List<Data>();

    try {
        URL url = new URL(myurl);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        // Starts the query
        conn.connect();
        response = conn.getResponseCode();
        is = conn.getInputStream();
        if (response == 200) {
            String responseBody = convertStreamToString(conn.getInputStream());
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(responseBody);
            //  JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(is);
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jobj = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Data data = new Data();
                data.setId(jobj.getInt("id"));
                data.setHeading(jobj.getString("heading"));
                data.setBrief(jobj.getString("brief"));
                data.setDate(jobj.getString("date"));
                dataArray.add(data);
            }
            return true;
        } else return false;

    } finally {
        if (is != null) {
            is.close();
        }
    }
```